# Why is 'sort of' pronounced /sɔːrdəv/ in AmE though /t/ is not between vowels?

Tags: american-english, pronunciation, flapping

Sort `/sɔːrt/`

of `/əv/`

Why is "sort of" pronounced `/sɔːrdəv/` in American English even though `/t/` is not between the two vowels `/r/` & `/ə/`?

Comment: In English, r is basically a vowel when it comes at the end of a syllable. @Hugh: Really? I don't think I would say "thangyew."

Comment: Perhaps your rule about the weakening of t is not quite covering reality.

Comment: There are louda problems in this. Geddit?

Answer (score 2):

It's not.  The phonemic (in the sense underlying) form is /sɔːɹtəv/ which is from combining /sɔːɹt/ and /əv/.  Because it is at the end of a word, the /t/ is also at the end of a syllable, and syllable final /t/ after a vowel, a glide, or [ɹ], and before a vowel, in many American English dialects changes to a flap.  So the pronunciation is [sɔːɹɾəv].  There is never a d, neither a phoneme /d/ nor a pronunciation [d].

However, a /d/ in this position would also become a flap.  So if the phonemic form were /sɔːɹdəv/, it would be pronounced the same way, with flap replacing /d/ (as in "sword of Damocles").

Comment: Please cite your sources.

Comment: @Kris, I learned about flapping from David Stampe's lectures when I was a student.  Since then, the facts about flapping in American English have become very well known to phonologists.  Here is a reference to a paper of mine: http://www.ai.mit.edu/projects/dm/featgeom/lee-howard74-divinityfudge.pdf

Comment: @GregLee Would it be fair to say it will happen after any (non-homorganic) sonorant and a vowel?

Answer (score -2):

It's a cultural thing and I don't think there can be a "Why" to it.

*The American T* on [americanaccent](http://www.americanaccent.com/pronunciation.html)

> **2 Middle of the Staircase [T is D]**
>   If the T is in the middle of the word, intonation changes the sound to a soft D.
>   *Letter* sounds like [ledder].
>   
>   *Water, daughter, bought a, caught a, lot of, got a, later, meeting, better*
>   Get a better water heater. [gedda bedder wäder heeder]

Snezhina Dimitrova, *British and American Pronunciation* [pdf](http://www.personal.rdg.ac.uk/~llsroach/phon2/sd10.pdf)

> T-voicing also takes place when the stressed vowel is followed by /r/ or by /n/, e.g., *party* /«på:rt¶i/, *reporter* /rˆ«pø:rt¶\ r/,
>   *twenty* /«twent¶i/, *hunter* /«h√nt¶\ r/. /t/ is also voiced when it is followed not by a vowel but by the syllabic lateral /l§/, e.g., *battle* /«bæt¶l/, *little* /«lˆt¶l/, *frontal* /«fr√nt¶l§/.